# How much can the pin move in two holes in two plates?

Tags: geometry

After hours of agonizing and researching in a futile attempt to solve this problem, I finally remember that there is a math forum in StackExchange.  So, I signed up for it and here is my problem.

(First of all, I'd like to apologize for the attached crazy hand-drawn figures.)

There are two plates and each has a hole (two holes total) as shown in Figure 1.  The holes are aligned and a pin is through them.  The pin will be under load and move to a side making two contact points with the plates, circled in red in Figure 2.  I also assume that there is no contact point on the other side, circled in green in Figure 2.

[image: pin installed on plates]

The question is how much the green dot will move, x.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under as reasonable assumptions as possible from the sketch (i.e., the green dot on the right still refers to the mid point of the pin at the middle height in the $L_2$ gap), the displacement of $x$ should be $$x=x'+\frac{D_2-D_1}{2}$$ where
$$ \frac{x'}{L_2/2}=\frac{(D_3-D_2)/2}{L_1+L_2}$$
Hence
$$x=\frac{D_2-D_1}{2}+\frac{(D_3-D_2)L_2}{4(L_1+L_2)} $$